# Fabric missing dsym for an iOS app

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm using crashlytics for crash reporting.

In the last release I'm seeing a lot of dsym missing warnings. I have tried to upload the dsym manually with no luck.

Questions

1. Is the number of crashes affected by missing dsym?
2. Is number
   of crash-free users and crash-free sessions affected by missing
   dsym?

I'm trying to decide whether I should pause my releases until I troubleshoot this, or whether the stability report is accurate even though the dsym is missing

Comment: down vote? leave a freaking comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer I got from Fabric Support

> Thanks for reaching out. Crashes with missing dSYMS will not be counted in the number of crashes reported by an app. This will also affect your crash-free users and crash-free session percentage"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll still get crash reports without dsyms they'll just live in this "unsymbolicated crash" page. **EDIT**: according to fabric customer service (accepted answer) these crashes will also not count towards the crash-free %s

A side note: But for symbolicated crashes, one of the interesting things about Fabric is that the crash count will always be "accurate", but you won't actually get the crash report itself until the next time the user opens your app and its able to send to the server. So it's common for the overview you see on Latest Release or the home page to say XXX crashes, but when you actually click into the release itself you don't see nearly as many. It just means that the user crashed and Crashlytics was able to log the crash itself, but not send the crash logs yet.

Side note but if you want to make sure you're getting dSYM generated you should go Build Settings > Build Options > Debug Information Format, and make sure DWARF with dSYM is enabled. The run script Fabric makes you add makes sure it's automatically sent

Comment: Just curious, where did you get that info from, fabric said the opposit

Comment: did they? I was curious about why there was a mismatch between the crash number and the total number of crashes a while back and spent some time googling. Cant remember where I found that piece of info but I remember finding it somewhere that seemed legit and it logically made sense to me

Comment: oh, I see your answer, yeah what I wrote applies to symbolicated crashes, unsymbolicated crashes are weird and only live in that unsymbolicated crashes page, Edited my answer for clarity, thanks

Comment: yeah, i'm still trying to figure out why my dsym is missing :(

Comment: check out the last thing I wrote, make sure that you have DWARF with dSYM enabled (note it matters which scheme your building on, debug, release, etc they all have their own settings), then make sure you followed the fabric instructions and added the build script under build phases - that should do it